# Set custom SoapServer response's namespace

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am creating Soap server side.

Is there a way to change default namespace for soap envelope, body and header tags?

To proceed requests I'm using following code:

```
ini_set( "soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$server = new SoapServer('myWsdl.wsdl');
$server->addFunction("GetDetails");
$server->handle();

function GetDetails(){
    $body_xml = '<GetDetailsResponse>
                    <Name>My name</Name>
                 </GetDetailsResponse>';
    $result = new SoapVar ($body_xml, XSD_ANYXML);
    return $result;
}
```

This is what I get in response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <GetDetailsResponse>
            <Name>My name</Name>
        </GetDetailsResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This is what I want to get in response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <GetDetailsResponse>
            <Name>My name</Name>
        </GetDetailsResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: The XML namespace prefix is not important. Why do you need to change it?

Comment: I was requested by other party to create response XML in specific form. And before leaving namespace like this I wanted to make sure, whether it is possible or not to change it on my side.

Comment: I don't know if you can control the namespace prefix with `SoapServer` and I'm not familiar with PHP but as I said, the XML namespace prefix is not important. This other party has something broken and instead of fixing it they are asking you to build a workaround. Why does the prefix need to be exactly that?